# Windows 7 Message Box

Tags: windows

Windows XP and 7 message boxes are different; how can I bring the old message box back?

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: If you want Windows XP style messageboxes, use Windows XP.

Comment: @LPChip so do you mean that I have to downgrade my PC to XP just becauyse of the messagebox?

Comment: Yes. The way Windows XP (or windows 7 for that matter) works  graphically is so different from Windows 10, it will be impossible to do. It is very much hardcoded into the OS. Skinning will get you so far, but then it still won't be exactly the same.